# How to return custom error in Angular service?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I have a service that will return http query, my caller will by default receive the result and assign it to a News[] object.

```
 this.service.getNews(url).subscribe((res) => this.news = res);
```

now I want to throw a custom error if any error occured:

```
getNews(url:string): Observable<News[]> {
  return this.http.get<News[]>(url).catch(err => {
  throw new Error("My Custom Error");
});
```

But I got a compling error that "cannot assign the {} to a Observable < News[] >"  because the error is not a type of News[].

So how can I modify the code to return an error without changing the returning type Observable < News[] >?

Comment: how about catch the error when subscribe executes?

Comment: what is the rxjs version

Comment: `Observable.throw` or import `_throw`:
`_throw(new Error(...))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of throwing your error, try returning an observable of it using `Observable.throw`.

The [docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch) specifically remind to return an observable from the `catch` operator.

Comment: URL needs to be updated